# Is it possible to add a set, get, didSet, willSet on Function variables

Tags: swift

Here's the base code snippet

```
var doStuffCallCounter: Int = 0

func doStuff() {
    doStuffCallCounter += 1
    ...
    do stuff here 
    ...
}

func doOtherStuff() {
    let funcOne = doStuff()

    funcOne // this calls doStuff()
}
```

Here's what you can do with normal variables

Is it possible to do something like this since it is possible to do it with normal variables?

```
var doStuffCallCounter: Int = 0

func doStuff() {
    ...
    do stuff here 
    ...
}

func doOtherStuff() {
    let funcOne = doStuff() {
        get {
            doStuffCallCounter += 1
        }
    }

    funcOne
}
```

Comment: Why did my question get a down vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible by doing something like this.

```
var doStuffCallCounter: Int = 0

func doStuff() {
    ...
    do stuff here 
    ...
}

func doOtherStuff() {
    // declare funcOne as a computedProperty
    var funcOne: Void {
        get {
            doStuffCallCounter += 1
            return doStuff()
        }
    }

    funcOne // calls doStuff()
}
```